# How to print via router?

Tags: wireless, networking, printing, canon, router

Hello I'm new to Ubuntu and I want to know how can I print files using a printer connected to a router via usb.

Printer: Canon PIXMA MP210
Router: TP-LINK WR1042ND

I already done that some time ago but I can't find the tutorial anymore... I remember the steps but I can't remember the host

What I did was to try to add a printer by going to System Settings -> Printers -> Add -> Network Printer -> Find Network Printer but I can't remember what is the host

My router's IP is 192.168.0.1

I searched on google for the past 2 hours without luck and it's driving me crazy because when I did it last time I did everything in less than 5 minutes

Comment: i found several sites on google. try searching for "printer usb router". that one could help anyway www.liutilities.com/how-to/connect-a-printer-to-a-wireless-router/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this way.

1. make sure cups daemon is running by `$ sudo netstat -lnput | grep cups` -----
   (Output will show what TCP port the CUP is listing, probably it is 631)

   - if it is not running do `$ sudo service cups restart` and `$ cupsenable`
2. go into your web browser and type `localhost:631`
3. In the GUI go to Administration > Add Printer ------ type username and password
4. next select "AppSocket/HP JetDirect " under Other Network Printer and provide the details as `socket://ip.address.of.the.printer:9100`
5. click Continue and provide basic details such as printer name and its description.
6. click Continue and now select exact printer model you are using with in the "Make" list
7. now click "add printer"

Thats all.... Now it probably will list your printer..

Comment: Thanks for your response but when I try to print a test page: Processing - The printer is not responding.

Answer (score 0):

Just to ad my 2 cents. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 a Netgear R6400 router and a Canon ip4920 printer. After selecting Network printer and entering 192.168.1.1 using the "AppSocket/HP JetDirect" which had a URI line with Jet Direct in it that worked but had issues. I made a different selection and ended up with this as my URI line

```
dnssd://Canon%20iP4900%20series%20(c1%3A8e%3A96)%200._ipp._tcp.local/
```

It worked so much better.